# Github: Fork Queue vs Pull Request

Tags: github

I'm getting started with a project with a friend on Github. So far, he has created the repository and I have forked it. I started making changes to my repository, committed, and pushed the changes to origin (my forked copy).

We're now ready to integrate the changes into his original repo.

What is the difference between the Fork Queue and a Pull Request? 
Do I need to send a pull request? Can he simply accept the changes in the fork queue and be done with it?

Thanks in advance!
Ethan

Answer (score 10):

- [The pull request](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/) is about reviewving and accepting commits explicitly send by other forked project back to your project.
- [The Fork Queue](https://github.com/blog/270-the-fork-queue) is about reviewing commits present in all the forked projects, but not yet present in your project. No explicit request has been made by those other forked projects for you to accept said commits: this is just you being curious about what others are doing based on your initial work.

In your case, a pull request is recommended, and will result in a review and a merge, and [many more features](https://github.com/blog/712-pull-requests-2-0).