# Git Branch Diversion Issue and workflow

Tags: git

I have a doubt whether the workflow that I follow is correct or if I have messed up the situation.

I was working on a new feature on the branch that i created locally and on remote. I am the only person working on it.

I Created it using:

```
git checkout -b rotation upstream/master
```

Now I made changes and commited:

```
git commit
```

and changes were pushed to remote branch:

```
git push origin rotation
```

My problem starts now. I typed `git fetch upstream` at this point.

Now when I `git status` I get,

```
vinayan@vinayan-MS-7623:~/QgisGitWorking/Quantum-GIS$ git status
# On branch rotatation
# Your branch and 'upstream/master' have diverged,
# and have 4 and 5 different commits each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I am confused by the branch diverged message.

1. Is anything wrong here?
2. Is there going to be an issue if i continue
   committing changes here and push upstream?
3. If something is wrong, what would be the best way to correct it?

I am quite new to git. Previously I have only used VSS.

**Edit:**

```
vinayan@vinayan-MS-7623:~/QgisGitWorking/Quantum-GIS$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:vinayan/Quantum-GIS.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:vinayan/Quantum-GIS.git (push)
upstream    git://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS.git (fetch)
upstream    git://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS.git (push)
```

Comment: What do you get from `git branch -avv`?

Comment: @ellotheth - i get http://pastebin.com/ncAB56Y3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of `upstream` is to allow for your own repo to rebase itself on top of latest from `upstream` repo.
That way, you can keep up-to-date with upstream, while pushing your own contribution to '`origin`' (which is a fork: a clone of `upstream` repo which you own).

You can push to `origin`. You can't push to `upstream` (you are not a contributor)
See "[What is the difference between `origin` and `upstream` in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-in-github/9257901#9257901)"

[image: upstream]

In your case, I would recommend, since `upstream/master` has its own history (parallel to your changes)

```
git checkout rotation
git rebase upstream/master
git push -f origin rotation
```

Note that you are force pushing (ie, recreating the history of your changes) on your fork `origin/rotation`: if no other contributor have already pulled from your fork, this shouldn't be an issue.
And your work on `rotation` will be based on the latest of `upstream/master`, which will simplify the [future pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178749/github-fork-queue-vs-pull-request/7181230#7181230) you might want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You pushed `rotation` to `origin`, yet you fetched from `upstream`. These are two different remotes and hence two different repos with different histories.

```
# list remotes
git remote -v
```

Comment: so i messed up..what can i do to undo this? I haven't done anymore work since then..